# Left multipliers on commutative $C^*$-algebras are right multipliers and vice versa

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In showing the multiplier algebra $M(A)$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is commutative, we are (in the exercise) first to show that any left multiplier $L : A → A$ (i.e., $\forall a,b ∈ A: L(ab) = L(a)b$) is also a right multiplier (i.e., $\forall a,b ∈ A: L(ab) = aL(b)$). But is this really generally true? If so, why make the distinction between left and right in the first place?

Comment: This is false unless $A$ is itself commutative. For instance if $A$ is unital then $M(A)\simeq A$.

Comment: I edited the title to add `commutative` for future readers. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: On the contrary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is commutative, $L(a)b = L(ab) = L(ba) = L(b)a = aL(b)$. You can see from this the importance of commutativity. It was used in the second equality and the last. In a non-commutative $C^*$ algebra, these two steps will fail, so in general left and right multipliers will not always agree.

Comment: My God, I completely lost the commutativity condition on $A$ somewhere. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It happens! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer shows that if $A$ is commutative, then every left multiplier is also a right multiplier.

The converse is also true, i.e. if every left multiplier is also a right multiplier, then $A$ is commutative. Indeed, if $x\in A$, write $L_x$ for left multiplication with $x$. Then $L_x$ is a left multiplier, and thus also a right multiplier. Hence, if $y,z \in A$,
$$xyz = L_x(yz) = yL_x(z)= yxz.$$
Since $z$ is arbitrary, we can conclude $xy=yx$. Hence, $A$ is commutative.

In conclusion, $A$ is commutative if and only if every left multiplier is also a right multiplier.